# React Native ,Javascript How can I customise android keyboard

Tags: javascript, react-native

In a react native app, I have a input type "numeric" , it displays numbers and "." . How can I replace "." with "/" or append "/" to the numeric keyboard display.

Comment: You may modify the input value by validating the keyboard input and changing ``.`` to ``/`` https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/keyboard

Comment: Can you give an example of you mean, the link didn't really explain how to do what you wrote is in your comment

Comment: @ObynoPac You would treat the input as a string and format it accordingly. You're saying you want 5.00 to be 5/00 in a numeric input, well it would need to show in a text input, not numeric, or it would need an input mask built into the numeric input

Comment: Thanks @Alex , I really want it to be numbers because in this case we want to use numbers only , something like this 5/00, please can you shed more light on how i could use this "or it would need an input mask built into the numeric input" or probably an example.

Comment: @ObynoPac What I would do if you just need the final input to be numeric is the following: Use string and text input to display: 5/00 but if you want the back end to be a number you would need to convert 5/00 back to a proper number 5.00 and parse it as the correct datatype (int,float,etc)